# Can I use only Dynatrace for performance testing in place pf Apache JMeter (or other Testing tools)

Tags: jmeter, dynatrace

Can I use only Dynatrace for Load testing/Soak Testing/Capacity Testing etc. in place pf Apache JMeter (or other Testing tools)?

I can see load testing reports in Dynatrace but is Dynatrace alternative to Apache JMeter (or other JMeter alike testing tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynatrace is an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tool, it will not create any load but it can be used for collecting various metrics from the system under test like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, Swap usage, HTTP calls, database calls, application-specific metrics, etc.

JMeter is the tool which generates the load by simulating behaviour of real user, but it doesn't collect any metrics from the system under test (unless you use a special plugin like [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)), it just sends requests, waits for response and measures time in-between as well as other metrics like connect time and latency, after that it calculates average response times and percentiles so you can correlate increasing load (number of active threads - virtual users) with the changing response time or errors per second or transactions per second

So:

1. JMeter (or other [load testing tool](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview)) is used for generating the load
2. Dynatrace (or other [APM tool](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/top-10-application-performance-monitoring-tools/)) is used for monitoring the application while it is under the load to figure out the root cause of the perf